# Cannot navigate to URL thorugh adressbar, only by clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jquery-mobile

I have a webpage that uses jQuery Mobile.

The page has a starting URL:

```
https://mypage.test.com/mobile/#start // dummy URL
```

And if I click on a link in the application then I navigate to another page, for example:

```
https://mypage.test.com/mobile/#secondPage // dummy URL
```

**So when I copy the second page url and add copy it to the adress bar it does not navigate to that URL, it only works when I press the button.**

Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you paste the code you use for the link and related data so we can help decide why the first link work and the second is not

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your `#` from the anchor element. The `#` is used to navigate to different sections from the current page. For example, Wikipedia uses it on the articles when you want to read a concrete section.

EDIT: I checked the documentation and it seems that it uses `AJAX` to load different pages and it needs to use the `#`. In the example that's available on the documentation the url includes the name and the file extension of the requested page:

```
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html
```

When you click to visit the Page two it loads with the new page and the url is

```
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html#two
```

Have you tried putting the name of the file?

Comment: This did not solve my issue **BUT** you did lead my on the right track when you mentioned the name of the file I tried to get it by getting the source of the page and in there I saw how they have solved the navigation. So if you update your answer to check the source of the file to get the navigation implementation I´ll accept your answer.

Comment: Are you using a unique file or you have more than one?